# what this instruction means? (db '%s', 10, 0)

Tags: assembly, nasm

I know that it's a format option but what does this instruction mean? I want to know what it does

```
db '%s', 10, 0
```

Comment: Do not add unrelated tags!

Comment: %s its used on c thats why i put it there but ok ty!

Comment: `%s` can also be used in Python, too and cetainly many other languages. Still no reason to add them here!

Comment: it's not an instruction

Answer (score 1):

```
db '%s', 10, 0
```

The `db` instruction in NASM and in many other assemblers allows you to insert any bytes you want in your program.
Here 4 bytes will be inserted: percent-character, s-character, linefeed-code, zero.

Comment: You might want to add that the more usual name for `db` is _directive_

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a format string for printf(). In c it would be:

```
"%s\n"
```